# Translate ?page_no=5 to <QueryDict: {'page_no': ['5']}>

Tags: django

When I send a query request like `?page_no=5` from the brower:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8001/article/list/1?page_no=5
```

I get the output in the debugging terminal

```
def article_list(request, block_id):
    print(request.GET)

<QueryDict: {'page_no': ['5']}>
```

Django encapsulates the `page_no=5` to a dict `{'page_no': ['5']}`

How Django accomplish such a task, are the regex or str.split employed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: we can inspect the source code to see how the `QueryDict` is constructed. It is done with a combination of **regex splitting** and **unquoting**.

This can be done by **using the constructor**. Ineed, if we call:

```
>>> QueryDict('page_no=5')
<QueryDict: {u'page_no': [u'5']}>
```

The constructor uses the `limited_parse_qsl` helper function. If we look at the [source code [src]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L391):

> ```
>     def __init__(self, query_string=None, mutable=False, encoding=None):
>         super().__init__()
>         self.encoding = encoding or settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET
>         query_string = query_string or ''
>         parse_qsl_kwargs = {
>             'keep_blank_values': True,
>             'fields_limit': settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS,
>             'encoding': self.encoding,
>         }
>         if isinstance(query_string, bytes):
>             # query_string normally contains URL-encoded data, a subset of ASCII.
>             try:
>                 query_string = query_string.decode(self.encoding)
>             except UnicodeDecodeError:
>                 # ... but some user agents are misbehaving :-(
>                 query_string = query_string.decode('iso-8859-1')
>         for key, value in limited_parse_qsl(query_string, **parse_qsl_kwargs):
>             self.appendlist(key, value)
>         self._mutable = mutable
> ```

If we look at the source code of [`limited_parse_qsl` [src]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/http.py#L385), we see that this parser uses a combination of splitting, and decoding:

> ```
> FIELDS_MATCH = re.compile('[&;]')
>
> # ...
>
> def limited_parse_qsl(qs, keep_blank_values=False, encoding='utf-8',
>                       errors='replace', fields_limit=None):
>     """
>     Return a list of key/value tuples parsed from query string.
>     Copied from urlparse with an additional "fields_limit" argument.
>     Copyright (C) 2013 Python Software Foundation (see LICENSE.python).
>     Arguments:
>     qs: percent-encoded query string to be parsed
>     keep_blank_values: flag indicating whether blank values in
>         percent-encoded queries should be treated as blank strings. A
>         true value indicates that blanks should be retained as blank
>         strings. The default false value indicates that blank values
>         are to be ignored and treated as if they were  not included.
>     encoding and errors: specify how to decode percent-encoded sequences
>         into Unicode characters, as accepted by the bytes.decode() method.
>     fields_limit: maximum number of fields parsed or an exception
>         is raised. None means no limit and is the default.
>     """
>     if fields_limit:
>         pairs = FIELDS_MATCH.split(qs, fields_limit)
>         if len(pairs) > fields_limit:
>             raise TooManyFieldsSent(
>                 'The number of GET/POST parameters exceeded '
>                 'settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS.'
>             )
>     else:
>         pairs = FIELDS_MATCH.split(qs)
>     r = []
>     for name_value in pairs:
>         if not name_value:
>             continue
>         nv = name_value.split('=', 1)
>         if len(nv) != 2:
>             # Handle case of a control-name with no equal sign
>             if keep_blank_values:
>                 nv.append('')
>             else:
>                 continue
>         if nv[1] or keep_blank_values:
>             name = nv[0].replace('+', ' ')
>             name = unquote(name, encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
>             value = nv[1].replace('+', ' ')
>             value = unquote(value, encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
>             r.append((name, value))
>     return r
> ```

So it splits with the regex `[&;]`, and uses `unquote` to decode the elements in the key-value encoding.

For the [**`unquote(..)`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) function, the `urllib` is used.